# Show form fields based on selected option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to show a different form field based on an option id in my form (not the value), but I get the same/double results no matter what is selected.

When I Choose ***Rent*** I get:

- rent selected
- own selected

When I Choose ***Own*** I get:

- rent selected
- own selected

What do I need to do to fix this?

```js
function rentown(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        rentcheck = document.getElementById("rentcheck").value;
        //alert(admOptionValue);
        if(rentcheck == document.getElementById("rentcheck").value){
            document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    
        if(nameSelect){
        owncheck = document.getElementById("owncheck").value;
        
        if(owncheck == document.getElementById("owncheck").value){
            document.getElementById("own").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("own").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    
}
```

```html
<select onchange="rentown(this);">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option> 
<option id="rentcheck" value="0">Rent</option>
<option id="owncheck" value="0">Own</option>
</select>


<div id="rent" style="display:none;">
rent selected
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="own" style="display:none;">
own selected
 </div>
```

---

Comment: You have the same value option = 0. That's why you have 2 results

Comment: if i change the value options to 1 and 2 the same thing happens. I also don't want the changes to happen based on the values, but rather the ID's of the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check the selected `option` id

```js
function rentown(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        var selectedOption = nameSelect.options[nameSelect.selectedIndex];
        
        if(selectedOption.id === "rentcheck"){
            document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "none";
        }
        
        if(selectedOption.id === "owncheck"){
            document.getElementById("own").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("own").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="rentown(this);">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option> 
  <option id="rentcheck" value="0">Rent</option>
  <option id="owncheck" value="0">Own</option>
</select>


<div id="rent" style="display:none;">
    rent selected
</div>
 
 
<div id="own" style="display:none;">
    own selected
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the responses. In my eyes they all seem correct to me, but since I'm needed to select based on the option ID rather the value, I choose this answer. Thank you @Thum Choon Tat and everyone else!

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the *selected* `option`, which you can do by giving each option a *different* `value` and looking at the `select` element's `value` - just checking the options' static values in the HTML won't show any change.

```js
const rent = document.querySelector('#rent');
const own = document.querySelector('#own');

function rentown() {
  const sel = document.querySelector('select').value;
  if (!sel) return;
  if (sel === 'rentcheck') {
    rent.style.display = 'block';
    own.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    rent.style.display = 'none';
    own.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="rentown();">
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option>
  <option id="rentcheck" value="rentcheck">Rent</option>
  <option id="owncheck" value="owncheck">Own</option>
</select>


<div id="rent" style="display:none;">
  rent selected
</div>


<div id="own" style="display:none;">
  own selected
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `nameSelect.value` to get current value of select

```js
function rentown(nameSelect)
{

    if(nameSelect){
        rentcheck = document.getElementById("rentcheck").value;
        if(rentcheck == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    
        if(nameSelect){
        owncheck = document.getElementById("owncheck").value;
        
        if(owncheck == nameSelect.value){
            document.getElementById("own").style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("own").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    
}
```

```html
<select onchange="rentown(this);">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option> 
<option id="rentcheck" value="0">Rent</option>
<option id="owncheck" value="1">Own</option>
</select>


<div id="rent" style="display:none;">
rent selected
 </div>
 
 
 <div id="own" style="display:none;">
own selected
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using your original `onChange` attr:

```js
function rentown(nameSelect)
{
if (!nameSelect) return;
if(nameSelect.value == 0){
 document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("own").style.display = "none";
}
if(nameSelect.value == 1){
 document.getElementById("own").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```html
<select onchange="rentown(this);">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option> 
<option id="rentcheck" value="0">Rent</option>
<option id="owncheck" value="1">Own</option>
</select>


<div id="rent" style="display:none;">
rent selected
</div>


<div id="own" style="display:none;">
own selected
</div>
```

Your issue was you had set both `options` to 0, and you weren't examining the `value` property of [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) (which is what is being passed in the `nameSelect` param)

Answer (score 1):

This works! You should compare the value but you checked whether the object is defined or not by "if (nameSelect)"

```
function rentown(nameSelect) {
   document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("own").style.display = "none";
   if (nameSelect.value == 0) {
       document.getElementById("rent").style.display = "block";
   }
   if (nameSelect.value == 1) {
       document.getElementById("own").style.display = "block";
   }
}
```